# Effects of Apache Shiro's roles and permissions in existing Data Access Objects classes

Tags: spring-data, dao, shiro

I am using `spring-boot-dependencies 1.3.5.RELEASE` for my application and it runs on `Java SE 1.8`. I am using `Apache Shiro' to map`user`groups in`roles`to`userpermissions`whereas I am using`DAO`(`Data Access Object`) for accessing data from database.

Let's say we have an entities such that

- `Employee` "has-a" `Department`
- `Department` "has-a" `Domain`
- `User` "has-a" `Domain`

Entity Classes: Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private Department dept

}
```

Entity Classes: Department

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="domain_id")
    private Domain domain

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

}
```

Entity Classes: Domain

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="DOMAIN")
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
    public class Domain{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;
        private String name;

    }
```

Now I would like to restrict `User` (a login user) to see only those `Employees` which are associated with the `Departments` whose `Domain` has an access to the `User`. Is there any way to achieve this without changing queries in DAO classes OR to do this with minimum code changes? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Which Realm are you using? If you are using the `JdbcRealm` you should be able to set `userRolesQuery` to a query of your choice.